# AWS Glacier - Why is my Content-Range incompatible with my Content-Length using the Golang AWS SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, go, aws-sdk, amazon-glacier

I'm trying to upload a file to Glacier using this code:

```
    fmt.Println(len(dat))
    uploadPartInput := &glacier.UploadMultipartPartInput{
        AccountId: aws.String("-"),
        // Body:      aws.ReadSeekCloser(bytes.NewReader(dat[:6000000])),
        Body:      aws.ReadSeekCloser(bytes.NewReader(dat)),
        Range:     aws.String("bytes 0-12962984/*"),
        UploadId:  initiateResult.UploadId,
        VaultName: aws.String("some-test-vibrant-glacier-vault"),
    }
    _, err = glacierClient.UploadMultipartPart(uploadPartInput)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

This outputs the following:

```
12962984
2019/12/11 10:57:10 InvalidParameterValueException: Content-Range: bytes 0-12962984/* is incompatible with Content-Length: 12962984
```

Can anyone tell me why my content-length is incompatible with my content-range?

Comment: Because the last byte of a payload worth of `N` bytes has index `N-1`?

Comment: See [this](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7233#section-2.1) for more: «The first-byte-pos value in a byte-range-spec gives the byte-offset of the first byte in a range.  The last-byte-pos value gives the byte-offset of the last byte in the range; that is, the byte positions specified are inclusive. Byte offsets start at zero.»

Comment: Apparently that was it.  It's always something simple.  Thank you @kostix